# Mix a cake in a bag

Tags: baking, cake, mixing

I saw a recipe on the web (via reddit) of someone making cupcakes in a sandwich bag, and then piping it out by snipping off the corners. The main reason was to save washing up (and in my case lack of a mixing bowl!)

I was looking to make cakes somewhat like [these](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/zebra_cake_76226) which are also piped from a bag.

The thing is I can't find the recipe for the original cake-in-a-bag, and I was concerned there would be something I was missing if I were to simply mix the second recipe in a bag. What do I need to change if I want to jump straight to mixing the ingredients in a bag?

Answer (score 3):

Kids do this in school groups or camps etc. to save on washing up and to preserve hygiene

Never had to use a special recipe before, just measure out the ingredients for what will fit comfortably in the bag

We use this for making bread, and even ice cream!